# jquery: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) and Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am getting error:Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
and Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

i don't know where i made a mistake can anyone check my issue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script >
  var myApp=angular.module("myapp",[]);
myApp.controller("mycontroller",function($scope){
    console.log("vinoth");
    $scope.users=[{Firstname:"Vinoth",Lastname:"Kumar",Email:"VNO@example.com"},
    {Firstname:"Vj",Lastname:"Krish",Email:"Vj@example.com"},
    {Firstname:"Vk",Lastname:"Khali",Email:"Vk@example.com"}];
});
  </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mycontroller">
   <div class="container">
   <hr>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add</button>
   <h1>All users</h1>
   <span class="clearfix"></span>
   <hr>
   <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
        <td>{{user.Firstname}}</td>
        <td>{{user.Lastname}}</td>
        <td>{{user.Email}}</td>
         <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalEdit">Edit</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalDelete">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
   </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Add New</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         <form class="form-horizontal">
                 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >First Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <input  class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter First Name">
    </div>
  </div>
         <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >Last Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <input  class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"> 
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><div class="modal fade" id="myModalEdit" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog"><!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Edit</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         <form class="form-horizontal">
                 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >First Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <input  class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter First Name">
    </div>
  </div>
         <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >Last Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <input  class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"> 
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModalDelete" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Are you Sure want to delete?</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Yes</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

can anyone tell me the answer

Thanks

Vinoth

Comment: `function` is spelt wrong.

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…FC%3A%2FUsers%2Fuser9%2FDesktop%2FAngular%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A163)

Comment: this error is also coming

Comment: @Vinoth see the below answer it is working.

Comment: @Hekmat if the answer is just fixing the typo, you should vote to close for a typographical error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Typo error in `funtion`.Use `function`:

   var myApp=angular.module("myApp",[]);
   myApp.controller("mycontroller",function($scope){

   ```
   console.log("vinoth");

   $scope.users=[{Firstname:"Vinoth",Lastname:"Kumar",Email:"VNO@example.com"},
   {Firstname:"Vj",Lastname:"Krish",Email:"Vj@example.com"},
   {Firstname:"Vk",Lastname:"Khali",Email:"Vk@example.com"}];
   ```

   });

2.Typo error at `var myApp=angular.module("myApp",[]);` it must be `myApp` not `myapp`.
**Example:**

```js
var myApp=angular.module("myApp",[]);
myApp.controller("mycontroller",function($scope){

    console.log("vinoth");

    $scope.users=[{Firstname:"Vinoth",Lastname:"Kumar",Email:"VNO@example.com"},
    {Firstname:"Vj",Lastname:"Krish",Email:"Vj@example.com"},
    {Firstname:"Vk",Lastname:"Khali",Email:"Vk@example.com"}];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mycontroller">
 
<ul ng-repeat=" x in users">
 <li>{{x.Email}}</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: problem is here `var myApp=angular.module("myApp",[]);
`